# How to remove Tree view Item on wpf C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, wpf-controls, treeviewitem

I want to remove a tree view item from a tree view `trvStructure` on wpf
i saw two options but none of them i working to me
'trvStructure.Items.Remove(object treeviewItem)'
and 'trvStructure.Items.RemoveAt(int index)'
but in the first option it just didnt work, i tried to put in to the parameter a tree view item that is included in the tree and it just didnt work
and the second one i didnt manage to fully understand how can i know the index of the tree view item, i saw some code about it in the internet but it didnt worked for me.
if it is helping the tree view is the tree view of a pc that i could delete files in it and when i delete a file i want that the file will be removed also on the tree view ofr tjat i tried to use `trvStructure.Items.Refresh();`
but it also didnt worked.
how can i manage to do it?

Comment: You should bind and template. The wpf treeview is a nightmare to work with if you build items manually like you would in winforms. Instead, you should bind and template. Hierarchicaldatatemplate is the thing to look at. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate?view=netframework-4.8   Use observablecollections and when you remove an object out one of those it then notifies collection change and the treeview removes it.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Answer (score 1):

i found a soultion, because i created manually the tree i cant use the `Remove()` or `RemoveAt(int index)` 
so if you want to press the tree view item you should do as below

```
`TreeViewItem  f = e.Source as TreeViewItem;
 if (f != null)
  {
     ItemsControl parent = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(f);
     if (parent != null)
       {
          parent.Items.Remove(f);
       }
  }
f = null;`
```